# Async responses with Aleph aren't being received over IPv4 but are with IPv6

Tags: networking, clojure, ip, compojure, aleph

I'm trying to get server-sent events set up in [Clojure](http://clojure.org) with [Aleph](https://github.com/ztellman/aleph), but it's just not working over IPv4. Everything is fine if I connect over IPv6. This occurs both on Linux and MacOS. I've got a full example of what I'm talking about [on GitHub](https://github.com/jonbca/aleph-test).

I don't think I'm doing anything particularly fancy. The whole code is up on GitHub, but essentially my program is:

```
(def my-channel (permanent-channel))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/events" []
    {:headers {"Content-Type" "text/event-stream"}
     :body my-channel}))

(def app
  (handler/site app-routes))

(start-server (wrap-ring-handler app) {:port 3000}))
```

However, when I connect to `127.0.0.1:3000`, I can see curl sending the request headers, but it just hangs, never printing the response headers:

```
$ curl -vvv http://127.0.0.1:3000/events

* About to connect() to 127.0.0.1 port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f920a004400
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f920a004400) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /events HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:3000
> Accept: */*
```

If I connect over IPv6 the response comes right away, and events that I `enqueue` in the channel get sent correctly:

```
$ curl -vvv http://localhost:3000/events

* Adding handle: conn: 0x7f943c001a00
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x7f943c001a00) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 3000 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3000 (#0)
> GET /events HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:3000
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
* Server aleph/0.3.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: aleph/0.3.0
< Date: Tue, 15 Apr 2014 12:27:05 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Content-Type: text/event-stream
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

I have also reproduced this behaviour in Chrome. In both the IPv4 and IPv6 cases, `tcpdump` shows that the response headers are going over the wire.

This behaviour occurs both with `lein run` and an uberjar. It also occurs if I execute the uberjar with `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`.

How do I get my application to behave the same over IPv4 as over IPv6?

Comment: When I run your example both ipv4 and ipv6 hang, what version of Java are you using?

Comment: I've used both OpenJDK 1.6 and Java 1.7u45.

Comment: Both ip4 and ip6 work for me on Mac + java 1.6.0_65 here